# Ubuntu desktop is not loading

Tags: 12.10, compiz, login

I have researched my problem on Google; but, I can not find a fix and I do not know why my desktop is not showing. Only the background wallpaper shows up. I also tried <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>F1</kbd> and removed compiz compiz-core then the same thing, and I also tried reinstalling `ubuntu-desktop` but again the same thing!

Does someone know how to fix this? I don't want to reformat my Ubuntu drive.

Fixed: apt-get upgrade

Comment: Possible duplicate of  askubuntu.com/questions/208346/ubuntu-12-10-shows-no-launcher-or-menu

Comment: THANK YOU your way of fixing this worked.
I tried every way that "should have" worked.. your way worked getting my machine to work on 14.04. THANK YOU x10000000

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>/<kbd>F2</kbd> and write your username and password. After this write:

```
sudo stop lightdm
sudo apt-get remove --purge ubuntu-desktop unity* compiz compiz-* -y
sudo rm -vfr compiz* compiz-*
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop* unity* compiz* compiz-* -y
sudo start lightdm
```

Try those command and see if this help you or not.

Comment: i see your answers after fixing my desktop, anyway thank you for trying to help, i fixed using "sudo apt-get upgrade" ! assalamu alaikum

Comment: good for write the true answer to help us thank you man walaikum aaalamu

Comment: Not sure why you have * on the commands, they don't work for me. Also the `rm`, thats not going to work as compiz is not going to be installed in the home dir?

Comment: also, neither this or the `update` resolved it for me.